# Normalize sub array lengths in a numpy array to do math on them

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, numpy, max

Been struggling with this for awhile tonight.

I have `numpy` arrays with sub arrays of data that have different lengths.

```
segements_np = 
[ [   30.    20.    20.    30.    40.    50.    50.    60.    50.    70.
      70.    60.    70.    60.    80.    80.    90.    90.    90.   100.
     100.   110.   120.   560.   510.   460.   430.   380.    380   370
     360.   320.   320.   300.   250.    80.    80.    80.    60.    70.
      80.    80.    70.    70.    60.    70.    60.    70.    70.    70.
      70.    70.    60.    60.    60.    70.    50.    50.    50.    40.
      40.    40.    40.    30.    40.    40.    40.    40.    40.]

  [   30.    40.    50.    50.    60.    50.    70.    70.    60.    70.    
     560.   510.   460.   430.   380.   360.   320.   320.   300.   250.
      40.    40.    40.    30.    40.    40.    40.    40.    40.]]
```

I don't know what size each segment is when I load the data file nor how many segments I will have.  I have script that breaks the data file into these segments.

I'd like to do various calculations on them, hence the `numpy` array.  For instance, I'd like `segments_np.max()`

However, since they are different sizes of course those commands won't work as is.

I've tried initializing the array size (zeros) to a size I know that won't be filled by the data I segment and then tried to add the actual data values into that (initialized array).  Thus normalizing the size of each sub array.  However, I am unable to initialize this properly and unable to copy the data into the initialized array.

I also tried:

```
peaks_np = array([ segments_np.max(i) for i in range( len(segments_np) ) ])
```

Would those work and I am doing something wrong or is there a better approach to doing this?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Would it be feasible to store a Python list of numpy arrays? One could then go `peaks = array([s.max() for s in segments_np])`.

Comment: Yes, so far is feasible.  Thanks!

Comment: For the record, I:
list(segments_np)
Then the code provided by dbaupp.
Would you like to officially answer the question?  thax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try storing the segments as a Python list of numpy arrays. You can then go

```
peaks_np = array([s.max() for s in segments])
```

Comment: If I still have your attention, is there an efficient way to return the index of these peaks in a separate array?

Comment: Try replacing `.max` with [`.argmax`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html).

Comment: Thanks for your patience, I should have known that.  Time for bed I guess.

Comment: No problem at all, happy to help :)